sharepoint page that shows posts from channel in newsfeed style
I have a Teams channel and a related Sharepoint site. I would like the home page of the site to have a page element which shows say the last 3 posts from the general channel in a news feed style.
I can see that I can add an element (web part) to pull in news eg an external RSS feed but is there a way to pull in news generated as posts in the channel. Do I create an RSS feed from the channel amd then use the RSS web part ?
